Best way to create and load numpy from a file
For educational purposes I need to write a Matrix class, a wrapper around a numpy array, which loads a numpy matrix from regular a text file in the constructor.
The constructor looks like this:
    class Matrix
    
        def __init__(self, path=''):
            if path != '':
                TODO

The file with the matrix looks like this:
2 3 4 1
1 2 0 2
6 7 1 3
2 5 1 9

My idea is to create an empty numpy array and then read the file line by line converting each line to a list of numbers and appending this list of numbers to the numpy-array.
What is the best way to 1) create an empty numpy array, 2) append a list of numbers.
For simplicity we can assume that the numbers are only integer. Also, I'm not allowed to use pickle.

Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read How to ask homework questions and [edit] your post.

The concept of 'empty' numpy array is vague, not as simple as a empty list, []. I'd suggest using basic python to load a list of lists of integers, and then making an array from that. An easier way is to use a numpy 'csv' reader, but you won't get as much python practice from that.
